# How to update the record in DB using codelgniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

[image]I am trying to update the record  in database using  codelgniter but  its not working. Please check the code and assist me where am i wrong? Please check the error also.[image]Please help me.

**Controller code**

```
public function update()
{

$id=$this->uri->segment(3);

$this->load->model('model_edit');
$a=$this->model_edit->update($id);


$data['userId']= $a->userId;
$data['date']= $a->date;
$data['firtsname']= $a->firtsname;
$data['middlename']= $a->middlename;
$data['lastname']= $a->lastname;
$data['mobileno']= $a->mobileno;

$data['landline']= $a->landline;
$data['address']= $a->address;
$data['city']= $a->city;
$data['locality']= $a->locality;
$data['email']= $a->email;


$this->load->view("index",$data);

}
```

**Model code**

```
public function update($userId)

    {

$query = $this->db->get_where('add_user', array('id' => $userId));

      return $query;
    }
```

**View code**

```
<body>
 <div class="container">

 <div class="tab-center">
    <div id="tabs">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Add User</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">User List</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div class="title">
    <p><strong>ADD USER</strong></p>
    </div>
<?php echo form_open("Welcome/add_user"); ?>

    <input type="text" name="userId" placeholder="USER ID" style="width:500px">&nbsp;
    <input type="date" name="date" style="width:500px">


    <input type="text" name="firtsname" placeholder="FIRST NAME" style="width:330px">&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="middlename" placeholder="MIDDLE NAME" style="width:330px">&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LAST NAME" style="width:330px">&nbsp;

    <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="ENTER MOBILE NO." style="width:500px">&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="landline" placeholder="LANDLINE No." style="width:500px">
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="ENTER ADDRESS"></textarea>

    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="CITY" style="width:500px">&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="locality" placeholder="LOCALITY" style="width:500px">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL" style="width:1010px"></br>

  <input type="submit" class="submit" name="SUBMIT">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">

<div  class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered" >  
        <thead>
         <tr>  


          <td><b></b></td>
          <td><b></b></td>
            <td><b>userId</b></td>  

            <td><b>firtsname</b></td>  

            <td><b>lastname</b></td>  
            <td><b>mobileno</b></td>  


            <td><b>address</b></td> 
            <td><b>city</b></td>  

            <td><b>email</b></td> 

         </tr> 
          </thead>

         <?php  
         foreach ($user->result() as $row)  
         {  
            ?>

              <tbody><tr >  
        <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('Welcome/delete/'.$row->userId)?>"><img src="http://localhost/CRM/img/delete.png" name="delete_image" ></a></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('Welcome/update/'.$row->userId)?>"><img src="http://localhost/CRM/img/edit.png" name="edit_image" ></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->userId;?></td>  

            <td><?php echo $row->firtsname;?></td>  

            <td><?php echo $row->lastname;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row->mobileno;?></td>  


            <td><?php echo $row->address;?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row->city;?></td> 

            <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td> 

            </tr>   </tbody> 
         <?php }  

         ?>  

   </table>  
  </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: check the `$a` variable, if it is an array or an object.
`exit(var_dump($a));`

Comment: bekt where  i can use this code

Comment: you can place `exit(var_dump($a));`  below `$a=$this->model_edit->update($id);`. every time update() called, you will get dump of `$a` variable.

if `$a` is an array you can use `$a['userid']` , if `$a` is an object you can use `$a->userid`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    function update($id, $data = array()) {
        $this->db->get_where('add_user', array('id' => $userId))->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply but  i am getting error...................................Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/Welcome.php

Line Number: 95

Comment: pass $data in your updata function like this..
$a=$this->model_edit->update($id,$data);

Comment: Chintan i tried your code but sorry to say its not working

Comment: then you need to check the your $data array using print_r in controller

Comment: Sorry for late reply i tried print_r($a) . Iam getting output link this

Comment: [field_count] => 13
            [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP
            [info] => 
            [insert_id] => 0
            [server_info] => 5.6.24
            [server_version] => 50624
            [stat] => Uptime: 23371  Threads: 1  Questions: 117338  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 85  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 78  Queries per second avg: 5.020
            [sqlstate] => 00000
            [protocol_version] => 10
            [thread_id] => 16988
            [warning_count] => 0
        )

Comment: ok,now try my updated answer then you get the proper array of data in variable $a

Comment: then you need to check the data available in dtabase or not?

Comment: data is available in database

Comment: public function update($userId, $data = array()) {
        $query=$this->db->get_where('add_user', array('id' => $userId))->result_array();
         return $query;
    }

Comment: i tried above code also in that output is only i am getting  Array ( )